# Optimize SQL subquery containing multiple inner joins and aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a select statement which is infact a subquery within a larger select statement built up programmatically. The problem is if I elect to include this subquery it acts as a bottle neck and the whole query becomes painfully slow.

An example of the data is as follows:

```
Payment
.Receipt_no|.Person |.Payment_date|.Type|.Reversed| 
          2|John    |01/02/2001   |PA   |         |
          1|John    |01/02/2001   |GX   |         |
          3|David   |15/04/2003   |PA   |         |
          6|Mike    |26/07/2002   |PA   |R        |
          5|John    |01/01/2001   |PA   |         |
          4|Mike    |13/05/2000   |GX   |         |
          8|Mike    |27/11/2004   |PA   |         |
          7|David   |05/12/2003   |PA   |R        |
          9|David   |15/04/2003   |PA   |         |
```

The subquery is as follows :

```
select Payment.Person, 
Payment.amount 
from Payment
inner join (Select min([min_Receipt].Person) 'Person',
   min([min_Receipt].Receipt_no) 'Receipt_no' 
   from Payment [min_Receipt] 
   inner join (select min(Person) 'Person', 
      min(Payment_date) 'Payment_date' 
      from Payment
      where Payment.reversed != 'R' and Payment.Type != 'GX' 
      group by Payment.Person) [min_date] 
   on [min_date].Person= [min_Receipt].Person and [min_date].Payment_date = [min_Receipt].Payment_date 
   where [min_Receipt].reversed != 'R' and [min_Receipt].Type != 'GX' 
   group by [min_Receipt].Person) [1stPayment] 
on [1stPayment].Receipt_no = Payment.Receipt_no
```

This retrieves the first payment of each person by .Payment_date (ascending), .Receipt_no (ascending) where .type is not 'GX' and .Reversed is not 'R'. As Follows:

```
Payment
.Receipt_No|.Person|.Payment_date
          5|John   |01/01/2001
          3|David  |15/04/2003
          8|Mike   |27/11/2004
```

### Following Ahmads post -

From the following results

```
(3|David  |15/04/2003) 
and (9|David  |15/04/2003)
```

I would only want the record with the lowest receipt_no. So

```
(3|David  |15/04/2003)
```

So I added the aggregate function 'min(Payment.receipt_no)' grouping by person.

Query 1.

```
select min(Payment.Person) 'Person',
    min(Payment.receipt_no) 'receipt_no'
from
   Payment a
where
  a.type<>'GX' and (a.reversed not in ('R') or a.reversed is null)
and a.payment_date = 
  (select min(payment_date) from Payment i 
  where i.Person=a.Person and i.type <> 'GX' 
  and (i.reversed not in ('R') or i.reversed is null))
group by a.Person
```

I added this as a subquery within my much larger query, however it still ran very slowly. So I tried rewriting the query whilst trying to avoid the use of aggregate functions and came up with the following.

Query 2.

```
SELECT
    receipt_no,
    person,
    payment_date,
    amount
FROM
    payment a
WHERE 
    receipt_no IN 
    (SELECT 
       top 1 i.receipt_no 
    FROM 
        payment i 
    WHERE 
        (i.reversed NOT IN ('R') OR i.reversed IS NULL) 
        AND i.type<>'GX' 
        AND i.person = a.person 
    ORDER BY i.payment_date DESC, i.receipt_no ASC)
```

Which I wouldn't necessarily think as more efficient. In fact if I run the two queries side by side on my larger data set Query 1. completes in a matter of milliseconds where as Query 2. takes several seconds.

However if I then add them as subqueries within a much larger query, the larger query completes in hours using Query 1. and completes in 40 seconds using Query 2.

I can only attribute this to the use of aggregate functions in one and not the other.

Comment: what is the database you are working with?

Comment: The Database I'm working with is Visual dataflex 14.0 with a Sql server 2008 R2 back end. However any Sql commands I use would have to be backwardly compatible to atleast Sql server 2005. Preferably sql server 2000 if possible.

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Following a comment from CodeReview -

I've also re-written the query using the [Rank()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) command as suggested.

Query 3.

```
left join 
    (select 
        a.Person, 
        a.amount,
        (rank () over (Partition by a.Person order by a.payment_date desc, a.receipt_no desc)) 'Ranked' 
    from 
        Payment a
    Where 
        (a.reversed not in ('R') or a.reversed is null) 
        and a.type != 'GX'
    ) [lastPayment]  
on 
    [lastPayment].Person = [Person].Person 
    and [lastPayment].ranked = 1
```

This method has also resulted in the speeding up the larger query, the larger query now taking some 28 seconds

However [Rank()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) is only supprted from SQL 2005 upwards.

Comment: I've selected this one as the answer as this would have been the answer I applied if only I didn't have to keep in mind backward compatibility with SQL 2000.

Answer (score 1):

How do you distinguish the payments

```
    (3|David  |15/04/2003) 
and (9|David  |15/04/2003)
```

These are both done by the same. Unless the time is different, then this query should work fine:

```
select 
    receipt_no,
    person,
    payment_date
from
    payment a
where
    type<>'GX' and (reversed not in ('R') or reversed is null)

  and payment_date = 
     (select min(payment_date) from payment i 
      where i.person=a.person and i.type <> 'GX' 
      and (i.reversed not in ('R') or i.reversed is null))
order by person,payment_date desc
```

I have set up and tested this query on SQLFiddle, but I am not sure about the performance, since I don't have the amount of data that you have. So check and let me know

===

## [SQL Fiddle Demo for the Question above](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7b813/14)